# jQuery change title to h1 title in activepage

Tags: jquery, html, function, title, page-title

How can I change my active page title to h1 title or h1 content?

HTML

```
<section id="contact" class="page_content">
            <h2 title="Contact">Contact</h2>  
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
$("ul.pages li").click(function() {
     $("ul.pages li").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active"); 
     $(".page_content").hide();
     var activepage = $(this).find("a").attr("href")
     $(activepage).show();                          
     return false;
});
```

Comment: I want change full page title to active page h1 title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
$("ul.pages li").click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active'); 
     $(".page_content").hide();
     var activepage = $('a', this).attr("href");
     $(activepage).show();
     document.title = $('h1', activepage).first().text();   
     $('title').text( document.title );                        
     return false;
});
```

Comment: after In order to change what you need to write

Comment: @BlitzerClarck What are you asking?

Comment: This code does not change the title

Comment: @BlitzerClarck Updated it. Also made the inactive page `hide` not `remove`.

Comment: yes awesome thanks dude u r great

Comment: @BlitzerClarck Remember to accept. :)

Answer (score 0):

add id:
     <h1 id="mytitle" title="contact">contact</h1>

```
 $("ul.pages li").click(function() {
    $("ul.pages li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".page_content").hide();
    var activepage = $(this).find("a").attr("href")
    $(activepage).show();

    // NEW:
    $("#mytitle").text("Hello this is changed");
    $("#mytitle").attr("title","we can also change here");     

    return false;
});
```

hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I want change page title dude not h1 title thanks

Answer (score 0):

make the title attribute match with the id of the current page, then

```
$("ul.pages li").click(function() {
     $("ul.pages li").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active"); 
     $(".page_content").hide();
     var activepage = $(this).find("a").attr("href")
     $(activepage).show();       
     $("h1[title="+activepage+"]").html("The new Title");
     return false;
});
```

Comment: sorry but Im new I'm trying to learn not working this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of the `title` of the page, you can try:

```
var current = $('h1').attr('title')
$('title').text(current)

// or document.title = current;
```